# activity onPause how to save the interface data

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, onpause

Hello I have in my app 2 activities and I want that when I switch between them the user interface and the Variables wont change is there any way to do it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What are the data types of the variables?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410259/saving-activity-state-in-the-onpause

Comment: int, Double and spinner position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save primitive data type (string,int,boolean etc.. ) use SharedPreferences, that will save your values permanently, untill user reinstall (clear data) application. Shared Preferences works like this

```
// save string in sharedPreferences
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("some_key", string); // here string is the value you want to save
                    editor.commit();
```

// restore string in sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
string = settings.getString("some_key", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences seem like the simplest way for you to achieve it, as you can use the SharedPreferences methods to save anything (well, any basic datatype) persistently.

```
/**
 * Retrieves data from sharedpreferences
 * @param c the application context
 * @param pref the preference to be retrieved
 * @return the stored JSON-formatted String containing the data 
 */
public static String getStoredJSONData(Context c, String pref) {
    if (c != null) {
        SharedPreferences sPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sPrefs.getString(pref, null);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
* Stores the most recent data into sharedpreferences
* @param c the application context
* @param pref the preference to be stored
* @param policyData the data to be stored
*/
public static void setStoredJSONData(Context c, String pref, String policyData) {
    if (c != null) {
        SharedPreferences sPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(pref, policyData);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Where the string 'pref' is a tag used to refer to that specific piece of data, so for example: "taylor.matt.data1" would refer to a piece of data and could be used to retrieve or store it from SharedPreferences.

Comment: there any better way to do it with large amount of data cause I have something like 30 int, 10 double and 10 spinner position.

Comment: You could store all of that data in a single JSON object, then store and retrieve that, but either way it takes up memory, either as sharedpreferences or as variables

Comment: how you add it a double value

Comment: The `SharedPreferences.Editor` has a `.putFloat()` method. Depending on your variable precision, you could either use that, or store it as a String then just parse it when retrieving it